# Retrieve data from SQLite on android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to read data from SQLite in android using three parameters, id, name and date. For example, id="number" and name="something" and date between ("first date", "second date"). the problem is that, i cannot figure out what to do with ***the last function***. There are two more parameters left and i dont know what to do or where to place it. So does anyone have any experience and familiar with this code style and can share or help me? (I take this code from book too and there was not any solution for related to this at all in the book.)

```
//Table person; It contain the same attribute as Person class
public static final class PersonTable 
{
    public static final String NAME = "Persons";
    public static final class Cols 
    {
        static final String ID = "id";
        static final String NAME = "name";
        static final String DATE = "date";
    }
}    



public class PersonCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper 
{
        public PersonCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor)
    {
            super(cursor);
        }

    public Person getPerson() 
    {
            int id = geIntI(getColumnIndex(PersonTable.Cols.ID));
            String name = getString(getColumnIndex(PersonTable.Cols.NAME));
            long date = getLong(getColumnIndex(PersonTable.Cols.DATE));


            Person Person = new Person();
            Person.id(id);
            Person.setDate(new Date(date));
            Person.setName(name);

            return Person;
        }
    }
}


private PersonCursorWrapper queryPersons(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) 
{
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query
    (
        PersonTable.NAME,
        null, 
        whereClause,
        whereArgs,
        null, 
        null, 
        null  
    );

        return new PersonCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }



public Person getPerson(int id, String name, String date) 
{
    PersonCursorWrapper cursor = queryPersons(
        PersonTable.Cols.ID + " = ?"+" "+ 
        PersonTable.Cols.NAME + " = ?"+" "+ 
        PersonTable.Cols.DATE + " = ?", 
        new String[] { id.toString() }
        );

    try 
    {
                if (cursor.getCount() == 0) 
                {
                    return null;
                }

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getPerson();
    } 
    finally 
    {
                cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which method you mean? Do you mean `mDatabase.query(...)`  ?

Comment: @AbdulhamidDhaiban mDatabase is an instant of SQLiteDatabase class. And i dont understand it well too. I found it in the book.

Comment: We don't know what book you are referring to, so I'm not sure why are you are mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

You have three parameter markers (`?`), so you have to give it three parameters:

```
cursor = queryPersons(
    ...,
    new String[] { id.toString(), name, date }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For android sqlite database operations you can simply use SQLiteOpenHelper class provided with android.

This is a complete implementation for your case with SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHandler2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database details
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname.db";

// Table names
private static String TABLE_PERSON = "person";

// Table Columns name
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "workout_id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "exercise_id";

// Create queries
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PERSON = "CREATE TABLE " +         TABLE_PERSON + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

public DatabaseHandler2(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PERSON);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_TABLE_PERSON);
}


public Person getPerson(int id) {
    Person person = new Person();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PERSON + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=" + id;
    SQLiteDatabase rdb;
    rdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = rdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            person.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            person.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    rdb.close();

    return person;
}

public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PERSON;
    SQLiteDatabase rdb;
    rdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = rdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            person.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            personList.add(person);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    rdb.close();

    return personList;
}

public void savePerson(Person person) {
    SQLiteDatabase wdb;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, person.getId());
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, person.getName());
    wdb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = wdb.insert(TABLE_PERSON, null, values);
    wdb.close();
}

public void deletePerson(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_PERSON, COLUMN_ID + "='" + id + "'", null);
    db.close();
}

public boolean renamePerson(int id, String newName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, newName);

    int numOfRowsEffected = db.update(TABLE_PERSON, values, COLUMN_ID + "='" + id + "'", null);
    db.close();
    return numOfRowsEffected > 0 ? true : false;
}
}
```

Here is the Person class

public class Person {

```
private int id;
private String name;

public Person() {
}

public Person(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: @dra , actually, my question is about getPerson function only. First it must query with condition. For example, name ="something" and id="number". And second, can i have another alternative solution without using something like SQLiteDatabase.execute ("command"), but following something similar to the last function? And still thx for trying to help.

Comment: My answer has a getPerson() funtion